# How to configure amqp-outbound adapter for ack/nack and return queues using DSL?

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit, spring-integration-dsl

I want to repeat [following example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/amqp/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/integration/spring-integration-confirms-context.xml) using DSL

config from example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-amqp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp"
    xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
    xmlns:int-stream="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp https://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp/spring-integration-amqp.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration https://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream https://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream/spring-integration-stream.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit https://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- From STDIN To RabbitMQ -->

    <int-stream:stdin-channel-adapter id="consoleIn"
        channel="toRabbit">
        <int:poller fixed-delay="1000" max-messages-per-poll="1" />
    </int-stream:stdin-channel-adapter>

    <int:channel id="toRabbit" />

    <int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter
        channel="toRabbit" amqp-template="amqpTemplate"
        exchange-name-expression="payload.toLowerCase() == 'nack' ? 'badExchange' : 'si.test.exchange'"
        routing-key-expression="payload.toLowerCase() == 'fail' ? 'badKey' : 'si.test.binding'"
        confirm-correlation-expression="payload"
        confirm-ack-channel="good"
        confirm-nack-channel="errors"
        return-channel="returns" />

    <!--Confirms are correlated with the entire payload; for rich objects, we might just use 'payload.invoiceId' -->

    <int:transformer input-channel="good" output-channel="stdOut" expression="payload + ' sent ok'"/>

    <int:transformer input-channel="errors" output-channel="stdErr" expression="payload + ' send failed (nack)'"/>

    <int:transformer input-channel="returns" output-channel="stdErr" expression="payload + ' returned:' + headers['amqp_returnReplyText']"/>

    <!-- From RabbitMQ To STDOUT -->

    <int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="fromRabbit"
        queue-names="si.test.queue" connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

    <int:channel id="fromRabbit">
        <int:interceptors>
            <int:wire-tap channel="loggingChannel" />
        </int:interceptors>
    </int:channel>

    <int:transformer input-channel="fromRabbit" output-channel="stdOut" expression="'Received: ' + payload" />

    <int-stream:stdout-channel-adapter id="stdOut"
        append-newline="true" />

    <int-stream:stderr-channel-adapter id="stdErr"
        append-newline="true" />

    <int:logging-channel-adapter id="loggingChannel" log-full-message="true" logger-name="tapInbound"
        level="INFO" />

    <!-- Infrastructure -->

    <rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" host="localhost" publisher-confirms="true" publisher-returns="true" />

    <rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory" mandatory="true" /> <!-- for nacks -->

    <rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

    <rabbit:queue name="si.test.queue" />

    <rabbit:direct-exchange name="si.test.exchange">
        <rabbit:bindings>
            <rabbit:binding queue="si.test.queue" key="si.test.binding" />
        </rabbit:bindings>
    </rabbit:direct-exchange>

</beans>
```

I wrote following DSL configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class Config {

    @Autowired
    private AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory;

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow fromConsoleToRabbitFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(consoleSource(), c -> c.id("consoleInput")
                .poller(Pollers.fixedRate(1000).maxMessagesPerPoll(5))
                .autoStartup(true)
        ).channel("consoleOutputChannel")
                .handle(Amqp.outboundAdapter(amqpTemplate)
                        .exchangeNameFunction(message -> {
                            if ("nack".equals(message.getPayload())) {
                                return "bad_exchange";
                            } else {
                                return "my_spring_integration_exchange";
                            }
                        }).routingKeyFunction(message -> {
                            if ("fail".equals(message.getPayload())) {
                                return "bad_key";
                            } else {
                                return "my_spring_integration_key";
                            }
                        })
                        .confirmCorrelationExpression("payload")
                        .confirmAckChannel(ackChannel())
                        .confirmNackChannel(nackChannel())
                        .returnChannel(returnChannel()))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel ackChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow ackChannelListener() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(this::ackChannel, c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(10000)))
                .handle(m -> {
                    System.out.println("ACK:" + m);
                })
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel nackChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow nackChannelListener() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(this::nackChannel, c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(10000)))
                .handle(m -> {
                    System.out.println("NACK:" + m);
                }).get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel returnChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow returnChannelListener() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(this::returnChannel, c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(10000)))
                .handle(m -> {
                    System.out.println("RETURN:" + m);
                }).get();
    }

    public MessageSource<String> consoleSource() {
        return CharacterStreamReadingMessageSource.stdin();
    }


    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow fromRabbitToConsoleFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundGateway(rabbitConnectionFactory, "foo"))
                .log()
                .transform(m -> " response: " + m)
                .handle(System.out::println)
                .get();
    }

}
```

**Expected result:**
 for valid msg I expect to get response as well as acknowledge

for "fail" I expect to get message from return channel NO_ROUTE because of failed routing key

for "nack" I expect to get message from nack channel because there no 'nack' exchange there

**Actual result:**

When I send smth valid(for example `123`) I see following in the logs:

```
2019-08-27 15:41:14.165  INFO 1568 --- [erContainer#0-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=123, headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedExchange=my_spring_integration_exchange, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@c3d79cf, amqp_deliveryTag=1, amqp_consumerQueue=foo, amqp_redelivered=false, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=my_spring_integration_key, replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@c3d79cf, amqp_contentEncoding=UTF-8, amqp_timestamp=Tue Aug 27 15:41:09 MSK 2019, amqp_messageId=f009e667-b1c0-0476-daa9-be1a416be603, id=37a496ed-3224-ad3a-7924-5093a15482ce, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-T2HBnQO6gUpnmU-Y_g0grg, contentType=text/plain, timestamp=1566909674165}]
```

if I send `nack`:

```
2019-08-27 16:03:30.256 ERROR 15712 --- [ 127.0.0.1:5672] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'bad_exchange' in vhost '/', class-id=60, method-id=40)
```

if I send `fail` - no reaaction I see in logs.

Disregard of input message I see

```
NACK:GenericMessage [payload=nackChannel, headers={id=a79d3ce7-3c26-8ed2-f49f-6788f2a2faac, timestamp=1566911103243}]
ACK:GenericMessage [payload=ackChannel, headers={id=5a764889-ed36-881e-d2b5-842443031c2c, timestamp=1566911103243}]
RETURN:GenericMessage [payload=returnChannel, headers={id=2e808a30-859f-f09e-e317-008391092c63, timestamp=1566911103249}]
```

I see every 10 secs in logs.

How can I achieve expected result ?

### UPDATE

After applying Artem Bilan pieces of advice I have following config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class Config {

    @Autowired
    private AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory;

    @Bean
    public CachingConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        cachingConnectionFactory.setHost("localhost");
        cachingConnectionFactory.setUsername("guest");
        cachingConnectionFactory.setPassword("guest");
        cachingConnectionFactory.setPublisherConfirms(true);
        cachingConnectionFactory.setPublisherReturns(true);
        return cachingConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate() {
        final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(rabbitConnectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMandatory(true);
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow fromConsoleToRabbitFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(consoleSource(), c -> c.id("consoleInput")
                .poller(Pollers.fixedRate(1000).maxMessagesPerPoll(5))
                .autoStartup(true)
        ).channel("consoleOutputChannel")
                .handle(Amqp.outboundAdapter(amqpTemplate)
                        .exchangeNameFunction(message -> {
                            if ("nack".equals(message.getPayload())) {
                                return "bad_exchange";
                            } else {
                                return "console_exchange";
                            }
                        }).routingKeyFunction(message -> {
                            if ("fail".equals(message.getPayload())) {
                                return "bad_key";
                            } else {
                                return "console_queue";
                            }
                        })
                        .confirmCorrelationExpression("payload")
                        .confirmAckChannel(ackChannel())
                        .confirmNackChannel(nackChannel())
                        .returnChannel(returnChannel()))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel ackChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow ackChannelListener() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(this::ackChannel, c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(10000)))
                .handle(m -> {
                    System.out.println("ACK:" + m);
                })
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel nackChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow nackChannelListener() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(this::nackChannel, c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(10000)))
                .handle(m -> {
                    System.out.println("NACK:" + m);
                }).get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel returnChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow returnChannelListener() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(this::returnChannel, c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(10000)))
                .handle(m -> {
                    System.out.println("RETURN:" + m);
                }).get();
    }

    public MessageSource<String> consoleSource() {
        return CharacterStreamReadingMessageSource.stdin();
    }


    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow fromRabbitToConsoleFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundGateway(rabbitConnectionFactory, "console_queue"))
                .log()
                .transform(m -> " response: " + m)
                .handle(System.out::println)
                .get();
    }

}
```

But I see following error:

```
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<!!!!!!!!!!!!!_________________!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
2019-08-27 17:19:47.386  INFO 8260 --- [erContainer#0-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<!!!!!!!!!!!!!_________________!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>, headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedExchange=console_exchange, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@118db7e0, amqp_deliveryTag=29, amqp_consumerQueue=console_queue, amqp_redelivered=false, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=console_queue, replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@118db7e0, amqp_contentEncoding=UTF-8, spring_returned_message_correlation=7005b4d7-c9aa-8adc-fc5b-9500b9fd0961, amqp_timestamp=Tue Aug 27 17:19:47 MSK 2019, amqp_messageId=7005b4d7-c9aa-8adc-fc5b-9500b9fd0961, id=2774bee5-41aa-c35d-f89c-295215ac888e, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-PSJwpYRV24p5PXeCqdiIXQ, contentType=text/plain, timestamp=1566915587386}]
GenericMessage [payload= response: <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<!!!!!!!!!!!!!_________________!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>, headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedExchange=console_exchange, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@118db7e0, amqp_deliveryTag=29, amqp_consumerQueue=console_queue, amqp_redelivered=false, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=console_queue, replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@118db7e0, amqp_contentEncoding=UTF-8, spring_returned_message_correlation=7005b4d7-c9aa-8adc-fc5b-9500b9fd0961, amqp_timestamp=Tue Aug 27 17:19:47 MSK 2019, amqp_messageId=7005b4d7-c9aa-8adc-fc5b-9500b9fd0961, id=e98a892b-c635-4050-05e5-9b3334e353b9, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-PSJwpYRV24p5PXeCqdiIXQ, contentType=text/plain, timestamp=1566915587387}]
2019-08-27 17:19:47.389 ERROR 8260 --- [ 127.0.0.1:5672] o.s.a.r.c.PublisherCallbackChannelImpl   : Exception delivering confirm

org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application.ackChannel'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<!!!!!!!!!!!!!_________________!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>, headers={amqp_publishConfirm=true, id=f2f6187f-251f-43ed-d243-c2bc1796138e, timestamp=1566915587388}]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:453) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:401) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:431) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AbstractAmqpOutboundEndpoint.handleConfirm(AbstractAmqpOutboundEndpoint.java:580) ~[spring-integration-amqp-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint.confirm(AmqpOutboundEndpoint.java:139) ~[spring-integration-amqp-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.handleConfirm(RabbitTemplate.java:2447) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.doHandleConfirm(PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.java:1033) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.doProcessAck(PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.java:980) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.processAck(PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.java:937) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.handleAck(PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.java:923) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.callConfirmListeners(ChannelN.java:492) ~[amqp-client-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:369) ~[amqp-client-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:178) ~[amqp-client-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:111) ~[amqp-client-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:670) ~[amqp-client-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$300(AMQConnection.java:48) ~[amqp-client-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:597) ~[amqp-client-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:138) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted


2019-08-27 17:19:48.388 ERROR 8260 --- [ 127.0.0.1:5672] o.s.a.r.c.PublisherCallbackChannelImpl   : Exception delivering confirm

org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application.ackChannel'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=, headers={amqp_publishConfirm=true, id=ce829fbe-8d5d-f8b4-34a5-3401803a397a, timestamp=1566915588388}]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:453) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:401) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:431) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AbstractAmqpOutboundEndpoint.handleConfirm(AbstractAmqpOutboundEndpoint.java:580) ~[spring-integration-amqp-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint.confirm(AmqpOutboundEndpoint.java:139) ~[spring-integration-amqp-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.handleConfirm(RabbitTemplate.java:2447) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.doHandleConfirm(PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.java:1033) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.doProcessAck(PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.java:980) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.processAck(PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.java:937) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.handleAck(PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.java:923) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.callConfirmListeners(ChannelN.java:492) ~[amqp-client-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:369) ~[amqp-client-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:178) ~[amqp-client-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:111) ~[amqp-client-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:670) ~[amqp-client-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$300(AMQConnection.java:48) ~[amqp-client-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:597) ~[amqp-client-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:138) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

### Update 2

After next portions of tips I have following configuration:

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel ackChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow ackChannelListener() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(ackChannel())
            .handle(m -> {
                System.out.println("ACK:" + m);
            })
            .get();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel nackChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow nackChannelListener() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(nackChannel())
            .handle(m -> {
                System.out.println("NACK:" + m);
            }).get();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel returnChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow returnChannelListener() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(returnChannel())
            .handle(m -> {
                System.out.println("RETURN:" + m);
            }).get();
}
```

console output:

```
correct_message
2019-08-27 17:35:43.025  INFO 2684 --- [erContainer#0-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=correct_message, headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedExchange=console_exchange, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@65c2b5a5, amqp_deliveryTag=8, amqp_consumerQueue=console_queue, amqp_redelivered=false, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=console_queue, replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@65c2b5a5, amqp_contentEncoding=UTF-8, spring_returned_message_correlation=6c44fb68-f7f8-c911-8dda-517171a2b022, amqp_timestamp=Tue Aug 27 17:35:43 MSK 2019, amqp_messageId=6c44fb68-f7f8-c911-8dda-517171a2b022, id=2092b749-325b-7151-17d1-aa8f7ce998d4, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-or-vX8P61nezVZOFiWjScQ, contentType=text/plain, timestamp=1566916543025}]
GenericMessage [payload= response: correct_message, headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedExchange=console_exchange, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@65c2b5a5, amqp_deliveryTag=8, amqp_consumerQueue=console_queue, amqp_redelivered=false, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=console_queue, replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@65c2b5a5, amqp_contentEncoding=UTF-8, spring_returned_message_correlation=6c44fb68-f7f8-c911-8dda-517171a2b022, amqp_timestamp=Tue Aug 27 17:35:43 MSK 2019, amqp_messageId=6c44fb68-f7f8-c911-8dda-517171a2b022, id=bb9ef444-54e2-8c6d-29b8-0fee3dd56712, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-or-vX8P61nezVZOFiWjScQ, contentType=text/plain, timestamp=1566916543025}]
ACK:GenericMessage [payload=correct_message, headers={amqp_publishConfirm=true, id=349e7e7d-32f1-6a84-c9f9-31f5b4f744a4, timestamp=1566916543026}]
fail
ACK:GenericMessage [payload=fail, headers={amqp_publishConfirm=true, id=8d38a9cc-449a-48bc-e08c-df5696763e7f, timestamp=1566916547025}]
nack
2019-08-27 17:35:51.025 ERROR 2684 --- [ 127.0.0.1:5672] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'bad_exchange' in vhost '/', class-id=60, method-id=40)
NACK:ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.amqp.support.NackedAmqpMessageException, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=nack, headers={id=96a90c78-50f4-3704-ab47-6df39ee4cdfc, timestamp=1566916551024}] [correlationData=nack, nackReason=channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'bad_exchange' in vhost '/', class-id=60, method-id=40)], headers={id=941cc78e-ec14-47f2-b983-e56df9a35c48, timestamp=1566916551026}]
```

As you can see correct message and nack works as expected but if I send fail message - I don't get any response from return channel.

Comment: Do you configure `setMandatory(true)` on your `RabbitTemplate` bean? Also do you have those `publisher-confirms="true" publisher-returns="true" ` on your `ConnectionFactory` ?

Comment: @Artem Bilan, I missed everything you mentioned. Trying to correct

Comment: @ArtemBilan, I am a bit stuck on **publisher-returns** / **publisher-confirms**. I can't find appropriate setter inside **RabbitConnectionFactoryBean**

Comment: The `RabbitConnectionFactoryBean` is exactly for the `com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory`. Those options are part of the `CachingConnectionFactory` - the one which is wrapping a result of the  `RabbitConnectionFactoryBean`.

Comment: @Artem Bilan, looks like I didn't understand your thought. 1. Is it correct that I have to use **RabbitConnectionFactoryBean** to configure  **CachingConnectionFactory** ? 2. Suppose that answer to the first question is YES then how can I set **publisher-confirms** and **publisher-returns** if it doesn't exist inside **RabbitConnectionFactoryBean** ?

Comment: Show, please, how do you configure a `CachingConnectionFactory`

Comment: @Artem Bilan, I don't configure it at all.  I believe that spring-boot does it instead of me.

Comment: OK. So, consider to apply appropriate `application.properties`: `spring.rabbitmq.publisher-confirms=false # Whether to enable publisher confirms.
spring.rabbitmq.publisher-returns=false # Whether to enable publisher returns.`

Comment: @Artem Bilan I updated topic with new error, please take a look

Comment: The `ackChannel` in your configuration is a `DirectChannel`. It's consumption can't be *pollable*. So, that `c.poller()` is wrong on your `ackChannelListener` flow definition. Also I don't think the `this::ackChannel` is correct. It must be just `ackChannel()`

Comment: @Artem Bilan, Almost everything is working. Adding information to the topic

Comment: Let me know when you have modified question.

Comment: @Artem Bilan, I've finished it

Comment: Yeah... Have no idea. Or you can share with us your simple project to play with or you can debug the code to figure out why the `returnCallback` is not called...

Comment: @Artem Bilan, I actually thinking how to share source with you? github?

Comment: Yes. GitHub is the best place. I'll pull your project and start it in my IDE for debugging. I don't mind if there is something missed in the framework code, since you claim that XML variant works well.

Comment: @Artem Bilan, https://github.com/gredwhite/spring-integration/tree/master/complete/src/main/java/amqp please tak a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use your `amqpTemplate()` bean definition, instead of that imported.

So, like this:

```
.handle(Amqp.outboundAdapter(amqpTemplate())
```

This way I get this in the logs when I send `fail`:

```
fail
RETURN:ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.amqp.support.ReturnedAmqpMessageException, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=fail, headers={id=bf68813e-51a8-5ef4-7f3e-224e54003e17, timestamp=1566920849918}] [amqpMessage=(Body:'fail' MessageProperties [headers={spring_returned_message_correlation=10df000f-5a92-6794-078a-35b0f3450a75}, timestamp=Tue Aug 27 11:47:29 EDT 2019, messageId=10df000f-5a92-6794-078a-35b0f3450a75, contentType=text/plain, contentEncoding=UTF-8, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, priority=0, deliveryTag=0]), replyCode=312, replyText=NO_ROUTE, exchange=console_exchange, routingKey=bad_key], headers={id=4f976428-9c10-9448-c556-94c3e962b8ce, timestamp=1566920849918}]
ACK:GenericMessage [payload=fail, headers={amqp_publishConfirm=true, id=a56cc7be-bdd9-9b81-940c-7cc8faef2512, timestamp=1566920849918}]
```

I mean the `mandatory` flag is really very important for the *returns* functionality.
I have no idea why `ack` is called as well, but that is already fully different story...

Comment: ohhh, my bad, sorry, I should find it. Thank you for your effort